# Are multiply-thrown Exceptions checked or runtime?

Tags: java, exception, runtime, checked-exceptions

I have an Exception chain in which `method1` throws an Exception to `method2` which throws the Exception on to `main`. For some reason, the compiler forces me to deal with the error in `method2` and marks it as an error if I don't, indicating that it's a checked Exception. But when the same `Exception` is thrown further down the line to `main`, the compiler allows me to ignore it and doesn't display any errors.

The original Exception in `method1` is a `ParseException`, which is checked. But the method has a generic `throws Exception` clause in the header, and the same object is thrown to method2, which has an identical `throws Exception` clause. When and how does this Exception lose the status of being checked / caught by the compiler?

Edited to clarify:

```
public void method1() throws Exception{
   // code that may generate ParseException
}

public void method2() throws Exception{
   method1(); //compiler error (if the throws clause is left out)
}

public static void main(String[] args){
   method2(); //ignored by compiler, even though the exception isn't caught or thrown or handled at all
}
```

**Edit:**
Sorry everyone, the question was based on a mistake... The main method actually had a `throws Exception` clause that I was missing. I've removed that and the code is now behaving as expected. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Can you clarify?  Does method1 throw the 'ParseException', who is treated as an 'Exception' by method2 and main?  Some method signatures and the try-catch-throw code snippets would help.

Comment: is ParseException a custom class? If so, could you add that to your example code as well?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile as written because both method1() and method2() would need to be static to be called by main. Once you make them static, the compile error is in main because it doesn't handle or throw the checked exception.

Comment: @ColinD - true, this code isn't exactly accurate, was just trying to give the general idea. method1 and method2 are actually object methods, and main instantiates an object and calls them off that object

Comment: @Jarle Hansen - ParseException isn't a custom class.  You can check out the javadoc: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html.  It's often thrown when `parse` is called on a `Format`.  For example, see `DateFormat.parse(String)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether an exception is checked or not is entirely dependent on what kind of exception it is: If it's a `RuntimeException` or a subclass of it, it's not checked; otherwise, it is. (And yes, `RuntimeException` is a subclass of `Exception` — one of the failures of the Java library design, but not the most major.)

What the compiler checks is the method signatures. So the actual exception thrown is irrelevant (for this purpose). If the methods say `throws Exception` then you have to catch `Exception` in your method or declare that the method `throws Exception`. Methods should always use the *narrowest possible* `throws` clause — e.g., *not* `throws Exception` but `throws ParseException`.

(I say "irrelevant (for this purpose)" because, of course, one of the *other* things the compiler will do is check that you don't throw checked exceptions that aren't covered by your `throws` clause.)

**Edit** The code you added in your edit won't compile: 1. It's calling an instance method without an instance, and 2. `main` needs to declare that it throws `Exception`.

This code solves the other problems, and (correctly) demonstrates that `main` needs the `throws Exception` clause:

```
public class CheckTest
{
    public static final void main(String[] params)
    {
        new CheckTest().method2();
    }

    public void method1() throws Exception{
        throw new java.text.ParseException("foo", 2);
    }

    public void method2() throws Exception{
        this.method1();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
CheckTest.java:27: unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown

                new CheckTest().method2();
                                       ^
1 error
```

Comment: So why is main fine with no handling, while method2 requires it to be dealt with?

Comment: oops! I just realized my mistake. There was actually a `throws Exception` clause in main's header... When I take that out the compiler errors I was expecting show up. Sorry about that, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

A checked exception does not stop being a checked exception. The way you can sort of turn a checked exception into unchecked is by wrapping it inside a type of RuntimeException and re-throwing it.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it'll be [`Exception`s all the way down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down) to the root of the call stack. If a method is declared to throw `Exception` (which methods very seldom should do), the calling method will either have to say it throws `Exception` too, or catch it and deal with it.

**Edit** As for the example in the edited OP, that won't compile. You can declare `main` to throw `Exception` if you don't want to deal with it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your compiler is not complaining about the issue in `main()` because it hits the issue in `method2()` and stops checking the syntax at that point?  Both should be an error.  Have you fixed the call in `method2()` and gotten a clean compile?